# Connect point data to one another using non-road data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analysis

I want to find all paths that connect 10 points to one another. Geometry of my route data is line data.

I have tried cost distance and cost path tools. However, this only gives me the shortest distance between the two, not all the paths.

As an example, I want to connect stadiums to one another using pipelines.

Comment: Do you want the [Minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)?

Comment: It is not exactly what I want but it definitely helps me towards the right direction. Is there a way to do this on ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to construct [simple paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_path).

You can use [networkx algorithm](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), but number of paths might surprise you. For example there 27 of them between 2 selected nodes of a very simple graph shown:
[image]

Fortunately there is a parameter to limit search depth.